# Turn Windows feature on or off is missing, Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-registry, regedit

I'm an administrator on the machine but the option under **Control Panel -> Add Or Remove Programs** is missing.  Does anyone know where the registry key is to enable this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the system key: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\
Uninstall]

this is the user key: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\
Uninstall]

for more info read this [article](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/1041/)

Comment: Yeah thats them, were all set to 1 for me so they were hidden, thanks for your help.